# Moving annotation in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have array with coordinates.
Then I pick annotation on my map.
My code:

```
var lon = [some_coord1, some_coord2...]
var lar = [some_coord, some_coord2....]
```

Next I do that:

```
var i = 0
do {
    var pin: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2dMake(lon[i], lat[i])
    var obj = MKPointAnnotation()
    obj.coordinate = pin
    self.myMap.addAnnotation(obj)
    i++
} while (i < lat.count)
```

Done!
But next I update my array with coord's, and I must update my annotation (like a moving car in map) 
It's one annotation, after update coord data (3 times)

[image: after update]

How update my annotation, without re-adding, so how to create a moving annotation?

Comment: you can't add annotations increasingly, you should remove previous annotations then add news. or you should update old annotations

Comment: how to update my old annotation, and if i have a new annotation I must add then in map...

Comment: you can store old annotations, when its coordinate is changed, you can remove it then add it.or maybe you can check the document whether there is an update method of annotation.if you have new annotations, you should add them